# Geometric sequence multiplication of consecutive terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need assistance with the following question:

On geometric sequence $q=2$ and the sum of the sequence is 30.
The sum of $(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_4+...)$ is $680$ how much terms on the sequence ?

(q is the factor between the terms, and n is the amount of terms on the sequence)

My try:
*$S_n=a_1(2^n-1)=30$ 
**$(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_4+...)=680 >>\frac{a_1^2q((q^2)^{n-1}-1)}{q^2-1}=680>> q=2 >>$ $\frac{a_1^22((2^2)^{n-1}-1)}{2^2-1}=680 >> 2a_1^2(2^{2n-2}-1)=2040$

 $a_1^2(2^{2n-2}-1)=1020$

then I pluged in $a_1$ from * and call $2^n=t$

$\frac{900(t^2\frac{1}{4}-1)}{t^2-2t+1}=1020$

but then I got complex answers here.

Thanks!

Comment: What is q? What is the n-term of the series?

Comment: q is the factor between the terms, and n is the amount of terms on the sequence

Comment: edit where the 2040 come from

Answer (score 1):

If
$a_n = qr^n$
then
$a_na_{n+1}
=qr^nqr^{n+1}
=q^2r^{2n+1}
=q^2rr^{2n}
=q^2r(r^2)^{n}
$.

The sums
$s(m)
=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_n
=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} qr^n
=q\dfrac{r^m-1}{r-1}
=30
$
and
$t(m)
=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_na_{n+1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} q^2r(r^2)^{n}
=q^2r\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (r^2)^{n}
=q^2r\dfrac{(r^2)^m-1}{r^2-1}
=680
$.

Replace the numbers by
$u=30$ and $v=680$
so
$u = q\dfrac{r^m-1}{r-1}
$
and
$v =q^2r\dfrac{(r^2)^m-1}{r^2-1}$.

Now we have to solve these
for $r$ (or $q$) and $m$.

If we know $q$ then,
dividing,
$\dfrac{v}{u}
=qr\dfrac{(r^2)^m-1}{r^2-1}\dfrac{r-1}{r^m-1}
=qr\dfrac{r^m+1}{r+1}
$
so
$r^m
=\dfrac{v(r+1)}{uqr}-1
$
and
$r^m
=\dfrac{u(r-1)}{q}+1
$.

Therefore
$\dfrac{u(r-1)}{q}+1
=\dfrac{v(r+1)}{uqr}-1
$.
Multiplying by $uqr$,
$u^2r(r-1)+2uqr
= v(r+1)$
or
$u^2r^2+(2uq-v)r-v
=0$.
This is a quadratic
that can be solved for
$q$.
This, in turn,
will give
$r^m$
and therefore $m$.

If we know $r$,
from
$u = q\dfrac{r^m-1}{r-1}
$
and
$v =q^2r\dfrac{(r^2)^m-1}{r^2-1}$,
squaring the first gives
$u^2 = q^2\dfrac{(r^m-1)^2}{(r-1)^2}
$.

Dividing gives

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{v}{u^2}
&=\dfrac{q^2r\dfrac{(r^2)^m-1}{r^2-1}}{q^2\dfrac{(r^m-1)^2}{(r-1)^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{r(r-1)^2((r^2)^m-1)}{(r^2-1)(r^m-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{r(r-1)(r^m+1)}{(r+1)(r^m-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\dfrac{v}{u^2}(r+1)(r^m-1)
=r(r-1)(r^m+1)
$
or
$r^m(\dfrac{v}{u^2}(r+1)-r(r-1))
=r(r-1)+\dfrac{v}{u^2}(r+1)
$
or
$r^m
=\dfrac{r(r-1)+\dfrac{v}{u^2}(r+1)}{\dfrac{v}{u^2}(r+1)-r(r-1)}
$.

This will give $m$
and $q$ then follows.

Comment: On geometric sequence $a_n=a_1q^{n-1}$ like on my try. and the number of terms on $(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_4+......)$ should by $(n-1)$ terms (and this sequence (of the multiplication) is also geometric sequence with factor of $q^2$ ) so what I did wrong ?

Comment: @G.gom `a_1 a_2 + a_2 a_3 + a_3 a_4 + ...` What is the *last* term in that sum? The difference here is that you are assuming $n-1$ terms in all, while Marty's answer assumes $n$.

Comment: but the last term on this sequence should be $a_{n-1}a_n$ cause, on the first sequence we assume that there are $n$ terms, and not $n+1$